# How do I use the Trim Function

Tags: arrays, vb.net, trim

I'm converting a web project from VB to C#, and I can't figure out how to implement the trim function.  Do I have to write a specific function, or is there a way to use it in the context of my project?  Here is the functional VB code I'm trying to convert. If you need more details, please ask.

```
Protected Sub ButtonSetup(ByVal Dr As DataRow, ByVal Btn As Button)
    Btn.Visible = True
    Btn.Text = Dr("Floor_Name").ToString.Trim()
    Btn.CommandArgument = Dr("Floor_File").ToString.Trim()
    Btn.CssClass = "GreyButtonStyle"
    AddHandler Btn.Click, AddressOf Me.Schematic_Button_Click
End Sub
```

Comment: What is the problem? It's basically exactly the same thing to Trim() in C#...

Comment: Im trying to take c# code and convert it to vb.  but c# wont let me use the trim function in this specific case.  when i take the Dr array, and I convert it to C# it wont trim.

Comment: First, it had a problem with the "ToString" ex: Btn.Text = Dr["Bldg_Name"].ToString.Trim();

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Indexer

`C#` uses the square bracket`[]` to access element of an indexer instead of parentheses`()`

## Event Handler

`AddHandler` and `AddressOf` are both `VB` keyword. In order to add an handler to an event, use the `+=` operator with the event as left operand and handler as the right operand.

```
protected void ButtonSetup(DataRow row, Button button)
{
    button.Visible = true;
    button.Text = row["Floor_Name"].ToString().Trim();
    button.CommandArgument = row["Floor_Name"].ToString().Trim();
    button.CssClass = "GreyButtonStyle";
    button.Click += Schematic_Button_Click;
}
```

Comment: he converted it to c#.  he basically did exactly what i asked.  so i shall counteract the downvote

Comment: Are you converting to C# or VB? You've said both in two separate comments

Comment: @Savanna I've added my explanation.

Comment: @Savanna the code is in C# as OP requested. "I'm converting a web project from VB to C#"

Comment: Then in a comment on the question... Im trying to take c# code and convert it to vb. but c# wont let me use the trim function in this specific case. when i take the Dr array, and I convert it to C# it wont trim. –  user3688776 14 mins ago

Comment: Either way it's a helpful answer now

Comment: @Savanna the reason why `Trim()` won`t work is because that there is no local function named `Dr` that takes a string as parameter; nor does that function's return has a `ToString` property that is a tring. The code in question : `Dr("Floor_File").ToString.Trim()`

Answer (score 2):

I work in C# and your code is VB, but it looks like you are just calling it wrong.

You have

```
Btn.Text = Dr("Floor_Name").ToString.Trim()
```

Which accesses the ToString method of the data row and calls Trim() on it. You aren't actually calling ToString. Change it to

```
Btn.Text = Dr("Floor_Name").ToString().Trim()
```

and it should work.

Comment: Well, the fix for Trim is correct, but that line will not work in  C#

Comment: Right, because it's VB. I think the OP just said the wrong thing and is actually converting C# -> VB. Anyway, they posted VB code, so I fixed VB code.

Comment: I did, which is why I said that I think they said the wrong thing. OP says convert VB to C#, but they post VB code. A comment in the question, by the OP said they are converting C# to VB.

Comment: Oh well, let the poster explain it